# Customer Logged In condition to display Block in Magento2

Tags: magento, layout, magento2

Is there any condition which checks customers is already Logged in Layout XML file?

I want to display "Sign In / Sign Up" links if customer is not logged in and "My Wishlist/ My Cart / Sign Out" links if customer is logged in.

Note: I don't want to display MY Wishlist and My Cart link when customer is not logged in to the system.

Comment: I can give you the idea. I know about magento1 not magento2. But you can get the idea from that. There are 2 layout handlers in M1 in `customer.xml` which are `customer_logged_in` and `customer_logged_out`. Both getting declared dynamically from `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Observer.php` and the function is `beforeLoadLayout()` . It should be available by default on M2 as well. But if not then you can do it like that.

Comment: The `customer_logged_in` handles are not available anymore in Magento 2. See this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106134/magento2-layout-handle-customer-logged-in